# Searching for a windows-1251 (m.b) character in a UTF-8 string

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

[image: some simvol]

There is a very interesting and incomprehensible symbol that I am trying to get rid of. But all my attempts will not succeed. In the browser it looks like this:[image]
I didn't find it in any reference book. Some decoders say that this is the windows-1251 symbol. The problem is that if this symbol gets into the RSS Feed, it becomes invalid [image] . How can I delete it? I will try to insert it here, if the system allows
you can see this symbol in the browser here:
https://iamstudy.ru/symbol.php

Comment: Not quite sure, but maybe it's a `BOM` issue (`UTF-8-BOM`). This encoding type adds a few chars in the beginning. If so, try converting it into UTF-8.

Comment: iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
I tried to convert it, it didn't help. A character-by-character search of the string shows that it is UTF-8

Comment: `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);`

this code helped me